# golang calculate full precision float number

Tags: algorithm, go

Used a decimal point of 200 as the precision, I need to calculate a number from atto to decimal number similar screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your calculation as text? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @NuLo `99707 * 10 ^ (0 - 18)` result `0.000000000000099707` in https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculator-precision.html, I try with big package in go but i get result `99707 * 10 ^ (0 - 18)` = `-997088`

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want calculate full precision number in golang (nano, atto, etc.)

Comment: What do you call full precision ? What do you mean by "calculate" the number, when you know it ? Do you understand what floating-point is ?

Comment: In many programming languages, including Go, exponents for floating point numbers are given by `e` instead of `^`. So, you probably want `99707 * 10e-18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `github.com/shopspring/decimal` package for this as well. This library can represents numbers up to 2^31 (2147483648) digits. Here is a simple code to do the calculation:

```
d := decimal.NewFromInt(99707)
d10 := decimal.NewFromInt(10)
dpow := decimal.NewFromInt(-18)
d10pow := d10.Pow(dpow)
dmul := d.Mul(d10pow)
fmt.Println(dmul)
```

This can simplified to:

```
d := decimal.NewFromInt(99707).Mul(decimal.NewFromInt(10).Pow(decimal.NewFromInt(-18)))
fmt.Println(d)
```

Output: `0.000000000000099707`

See [playground](https://goplay.space/#_7qFw-t3jEM)

Answer (score 3):

To get the values at precision of nano and atto you can use `%.9f` and `%.18f` in fmt.Printf() respectively,I created a small program to get your value of `0.000000000000099707` as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {

    powr := math.Pow(10, -18)
    numb := 99707 * powr
    fmt.Println("number", numb)
    fmt.Printf("\nthe value in atto %.18f\n", numb)
}
```

Output:

```
number 9.970700000000001e-14

the value in atto 0.000000000000099707
```

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in how to do this so I found the [apd](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cockroachdb/apd) package from cockroach that handles arbitrary precision calculations. You can use it like this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/cockroachdb/apd"
)

func main() {
    // 99707 * 10^(-18)
    n1 := apd.New(99707, 0)
    n2 := apd.New(10, 0)
    n3 := apd.New(-18, 0)
    c := apd.BaseContext.WithPrecision(200)
    res := apd.New(0,0)

    ctx, err := c.Pow(res, n2, n3)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx, err = c.Mul(res, res, n1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(ctx.Inexact(), res.Text('f'))
}
```

And it will output:

```
false 0.000000000000099707
```

You will have to be careful with the loss of precision that may happen and look at the inexact field.

Comment: I can calculate nano `0.536608955` ? `0.536608955 * 10 ^ (0 - 9) = 0.000000000536608955`

Comment: yes `n1 := apd.New(536608955, -9)` and then change the n3 from -18 to -9. Will you be doing calculations with these numbers or is this just for presentation purposes?

Comment: you can also use `apd.NewFromString("0.536608955")` but be careful to handle the return values